# NodeJS API can't connect inside docker container: DNS error occured

Tags: node.js, docker, deployment, dns

Error:

```bash
auth-service-1     | Error: getaddrinfo ENOTFOUND cluster0.random.mongodb.net
auth-service-1     |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.onlookup [as oncomplete] (node:dns:107:26)
auth-service-1     |     at GetAddrInfoReqWrap.callbackTrampoline (node:internal/async_hooks:130:17) {
auth-service-1     |   errno: -3008,
auth-service-1     |   code: 'ENOTFOUND',
auth-service-1     |   syscall: 'getaddrinfo',
auth-service-1     |   hostname: 'cluster0.random.mongodb.net'
auth-service-1     | }
auth-service-1     | 
auth-service-1     | Node.js v18.15.0
```

Dockerfile

```
FROM node:18-alpine

ARG SERVICE_PORT=8004
ARG NODE_ENV=dev
ENV NODE_ENV=${NODE_ENV}

# Create app directory
RUN mkdir -p /usr/src/app
WORKDIR /usr/src/app

# Install app dependencies
COPY src/package.json /usr/src/app/
RUN cd /usr/src/app/ && npm install

# Bundle app source
COPY src /usr/src/app

EXPOSE ${SERVICE_PORT}

CMD ["sh", "-c", "npm run start:${NODE_ENV}"]
```

Locally API is able to connect to mongoDB cluster but inside docker container it can't able to connect, it is raising DNS error.

On mongoDB cluster I've `Allow Access From Anywhere` and if it is working in my local machine without docker then it should also work with docker as the ip will remain same

Answer (score 0):

In the docker-compose file you should have a network option for each service, when they are on the same network this error will not occur

```
services:
 api:
  networks:
   backend
 mongodb:
  networks:
   backend
```